# Two's complement Using ONLY Logic Gates

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How can a 4-bit two's complement operation be implemented using only boolean logic gates (AND, OR, NOR, NOT, NAND, XOR, and XNOR)?

(This question was redirected to CS from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277093/twos-complement-using-only-logic-gates))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A two's complement operation is simply a one's complement operation followed by the addition of `1` to the result. One's complement is easy: simply invert all of the input bits.

The addition of `1` must be done with a 4-bit adder. A 4-bit adder is constructed using four stages of a 1-bit full adder. The 1-bit full adder accepts two bits, plus a Carry input, and generates the sum of the two bits, plus a Carry output. The following diagram is a 1-bit full adder:

[image]

We can cascade four of the 1-bit full adder stages together, feeding the Carry output of each stage to the Carry input of the next stage. The inverted (one's complement) inputs are applied to the `B` inputs of the four stages. To perform an addition of `1`, we apply the 4-bit binary value `0001` to the `A` inputs. The complete boolean circuit is shown below:

[image]

The above circuit can be reduced by noting that each XOR operation on the input of each adder stage can be replaced either with an inverter if the `A` input is a `0`, or a NOP (no operation) if the `A` input is a `1`. On further analysis, further reductions may be made to the circuit, as well.

Comment: If you need to increment, one half adder per bit is enough (you'll have the same result if you simplify the above circuit by considering the constant input).

Comment: Won't the Cout of each stage be generated from an OR gate? Can't help but notice you are using an X-OR gate to generate the Couts'.

Comment: You are very perceptive. The Cout can be generated by either an OR gate or an XOR gate. This is because the two inputs to that gate are never both 1 at the same time. (Create a truth table to convince yourself of this.)

But you should post your question as a comment to my answer, and not as a new answer to the question.